# PHP convert ISO 8601 timestamp to unix then back to ISO 8601

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format, iso8601

I have a timestamp

```
2022-04-22T18:23:12.263Z
```

I am converting it to unix timestamp using

```
strtotime('2022-04-22T18:23:12.263Z') // result 1650651792
```

How can I convert it from the unix timestamp back to the original? right now I am using the following but the output is not correct.

```
echo date_format(date_timestamp_set(new DateTime(), 1650651792)->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT')), 'c');
// result 2022-04-22T18:23:12+00:00
```

Also using the code below doesn't give me the fraction seconds.

```
echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.Z\Z", 1650651792); // result 2022-04-22T18:23:12.0Z
```

Comment: FYI,
timestamp represents the number of seconds since 01.01.1970.

`.263` after the seconds is "lost" when you use `strtotime('2022-04-22T18:23:12.263Z')`

Comment: Unix timestamps are whole number of seconds, so your fractional seconds will be lost in the first conversion. Also Unix timestamps are _always_ UTC and date strings parsed from formats including timezones, both explicit and implicit, ignore specified timezone arguments. If you want `Z` instead of `+00:00` you need to specify the full format string with `e` as the timezone part. Lastly, you're not going to get any fewer than 6 digits of subsecond precision out of any date formatting call in PHP so you'll have to finagle that in as well.